# jpa:repositories stops to generate the repository proxies

Tags: spring-data-jpa

This question has already been posted on:

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?133389-spring-data-jpa-1-2-0-and-jpa-repositories

With a project using Spring 3.1.3 and Spring DM 1.2.1, when I update Spring Data JPA from version 1.1.2 to 1.2.0 (and Spring Data Commons Core from 1.3.2 to 1.4.0), then the element jpa:repositories stops to generate the repository proxies for the selected interfaces.
Any attempt to uses such proxy generates an exception such as:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.osgi.service.exporter.support.OsgiServiceFactoryBean#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot locate bean named 'userDao' inside the running bean factory.
```

Any idea to solve this issue?

Regards
Pierre

PS:
EclipseLink 2.4.1 and Derby 10.9.1 are used.

The project's context and manifest and the full trace of the exception are available
on the link above together with a zip file of a minimal test project under Eclipse.